# How to replace File.listFiles(FileFilter filter) with nio in Java 7?

Tags: java, file, path, java-7, nio2

I have some file I/0 traversal code written in Java 6, trying to move it the New I/O in Java 7 but I cannot find any replacement for this kind of stuff.

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(AudioFileFilter.getInstance());
```

Namely, no way to filter paths only files, and it returns list of files so I would then have to convert each file to path (file.toPath) if I wanted to limit the use of File in methods it calls, which seems rather laborious.

I did look at FileVisitor but this does not seem to allow you to control how the the tree is traversed so I don' think it will work for me.

So how much of a replacement is Path for File in Java 7 ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using [Files#newDirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter%29) and [DirectoryStream.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html)

Here is the code:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException 
        {
            return Files.isDirectory(entry);
        }
    });

for (Path entry: stream) {
      ...
}
```

BTW, I omitted the exception handling in the above code for simplicity.

Comment: Athough if you want to pass the list of files to another method (which I do the files are processed on a different thread) bit messy that you ave iterate round the files and add them to a list

Comment: Instead of passing a list you could simply pass the stream to the other method. Depending, of course, on whether you control the parameter type of said method. If not you are absolutely right, it does not make a lot of sense to iterate one list structure just to add the content to another list structure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the new nio package, but I see a stream, and it is nowhere closed!

Comment: What about the FilenameFilter ? It seems that it is missing here.